# How to monitor visited websites on a Thomson 585 v7 router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, bandwidth, telnet

My home WiFi is being used by many devices, and they are taking all bandwidth, I wanna know which sites they are using, so I can block those sites in Parental control.

In the web interface there's no option to monitor the visited websites, so I hope you can help me find a solution using Telnet, or maybe a software.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [OpenDNS](https://www.opendns.com). From [their site](https://web.archive.org/web/20120528102812/https://www.opendns.com/home-solutions/parental-controls/), bold emphasis mine:

> Setting up OpenDNS parental controls is as easy as making one simple change to your wireless router. Follow our detailed instructions for your wireless router's settings, then choose the content you want to block. OpenDNS takes effect across your entire household immediately – from your family computer to your kids' gaming console. Because OpenDNS Internet parental controls **also provide you insight into which websites are being visited on your home network**, the service allows you to easily discover new problem websites. **If you see an inappropriate website appear in your account statistics you can quickly and easily block the site** and, if you wish, the category of content to which that site belongs.

And it's free!

Comment: Perhaps I am babbling about something irrelevant, but OpenDNS is now owned by Cisco, so they might charge you for it! _evil subscription sounds_